# Box plots with individual observations

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataset of 4 columns of values and I need to create a graph with 4 boxplots showing average and standard deviation, and I wanted to know how to also show the individual observations as points (with ggplot2).

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including (at least) a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: This said: At least for the first step which involves reshaping your data you could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971524/how-to-reshape-data-to-create-facets-of-boxplots-of-multiple-variables-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively simple, as you can add multiple `geom_`s in ggplot.
Here is a small example that showcases the `geom_boxplot` in combination with `geom_jitter`.

In order to also be able to show outliers in a box plot (if that is what you want), you can add color or different point-types with e.g. `geom_boxplot(outlier.color = "red")`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red") + # Add the boxplot geom
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1) # Add the points with a random jitter on the X-axis
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you very much! 
Could you please indicate me how to move one of the species to the left or to the right in this particular graph?

Comment: Are you asking to change the order, or create a space between the groups?

Comment: I wanted to know how to change the order (left/right) of the boxplots in a custom way